# Why does ShellExecute()ing cmd.exe hidden works?

Tags: c++, winapi, cmd

When trying to execute cmd.exe with the `SW_HIDE` paramter:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "cmd.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_HIDE);
```

cmd.exe is actually executed hidden! I don't understand why this happened, does cmd.exe's console window considered to be a "normal" window that accepts the `nCmdShow` parameter, or does cmd.exe when executed sees that I passed `SW_HIDE` for the `nCmdShow`  parameter and decides not to show the console window?

**Note:** I tried this code on Windows 7.

Comment: CREATE_NO_WINDOW is the way to do this. Console mode apps don't get a chance to create windows. The system handles that. ShellExecute is for shell verbs. For creating processes use CreateProcess.

Comment: @David Heffernan So when executing cmd.exe using `CreateProcess()` with the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` parameter, the system will not create any console window for cmd.exe?

Comment: Correct. That's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implication is that `cmd.exe` simply uses the `nCmdShow` argument to `WinMain` (or that it uses `SW_SHOWDEFAULT` which means the same thing) when showing its window via `ShowWindow`, without checking or modifying the value first.

It's not documented that it will work and so you shouldn't rely on it, but it's a nice side effect that can be a good way to run batch scripts without a visible window appearing.

Of course if you actually launch an interactive `cmd.exe` in a hidden window it will be quite difficult to ever make it visible :)

Comment: So the guaranteed way of executing cmd.exe without showing the console window is by using `CreateProcess()`?

Comment: @James I don't think any of these methods are "guaranteed" since fundamentally it's up to cmd.exe how it shows its window. Still it's probably pretty safe that this won't ever change.

Comment: So when `CreateProcess()` is used with the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` parameter, it is not forcing the application to hide any console windows it could display, but rather only asking the application to do so, and the application can choose to ignore this request?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: most apps ignore the `nCmdShow` parameter of `WinMain`. That value is also present in the `STARTUPINFO` structure used to start the process, and `ShowWindow()` checks for that value the first time it is called, ignoring its own `nCmdShow` parameter if `STARTUPINFO` is present. This is documented behavior.

Comment: @James: per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863.aspx): "*CREATE_NO_WINDOW
The process is a console application that is being run without a console window. **Therefore, the console handle for the application is not set.**
This flag is ignored if the application is not a console application, or if it is used with either CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or DETACHED_PROCESS.*" So Windows ensures that the new console process has no access to a console window.

Comment: @James There's a difference between a hidden-but-still existing console window, and no console at all.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter You mean when cmd.exe is launched with a hidden console window, when it writes to `stdout`, it is still writing to the same location in memory, but the console window to show the output is simply hidden (just like I can hide an `HWND` but still can set its title text)?

Comment: @James Correct, the window is still there, but hidden. If you had its  `HWND` you could show it again.